# How to configure AWS EC2 instance for remote port forwarding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, portforwarding

I have a local web server running on port 3000, I want to expose this web server to public. I have an AWS EC2 instance running, I have tried something like this on my local machine. what should I do to achieve the goal?

`ssh -R 3300:localhost:3000 http://(aws-ec2-url).amazonaws.com`

but it says could not resolve the host name.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to allow people to access port 80 on the EC2 instance and you would like their traffic redirect to port 3000 on your own computer? What is the `3300` doing?

Comment: Yes I mean I want to be able to access 80 on ec2 instance, but 80 is already in use, so I want them to be able to access port 3300 on ec2 which should be redirected to my local machine

Comment: I'm not sure if it will permit 'external' access to the port, but it's worth experimenting. You'd need to use the same SSH command that you use to connect to the instance normally, but include the `-R` parts. For example: `ssh -i keyfile.pem ec2-user@IP-OR-DNS -R 3300:localhost:3000` Failing that, you'd need to run a **proxy** on the EC2 instance that listens on that port and redirects to a local port that is redirected through SSH. I would not recommend it as a permanent configuration.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you so much, I will implement and inform you how it panned out.

Comment: How did it pan out?